# Output multiple converted files to custom directory using textutil

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, textutils

I need to batch convert multiple docx files to txt files and place them in a custom directory using textutil.

It seems I can do this with a single file, but not with multiple files. If I set an `-output` path while converting multiple files, it will only convert the first file.

I realise I could just move the files after the conversion, but it would save time in the future if this were possible.

```
textutil -convert txt /Users/evanjohn/Desktop/docs/original/*.docx -output /Users/evanjohnmeredith-davies/Desktop/docs/converted/*.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `textutil` gets to do anything, the shell expands the globs; because `converted/*.txt` doesn't match anything, it'll expand to just itself<sup>1</sup>, creating a file called `*.txt`, which isn't what you want.

Since there doesn't seem to be an option to specifiy multiple output filenames, you probably have to loop over the files one by one:

```
for fpath in /Users/evanjohn/Desktop/docs/original/*.docx; do
    fname=${fpath##*/}
    textutil -convert txt "$fpath" -output "${fpath%/*}/converted/${fname%.docx}.txt"
done
```

This extracts the filename first and then uses parameter expansion to get the desired paths.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, if the `nullglob` shell option is set, to the empty string.